# Combine the results of multiple select

Tags: php, sql, loops

I need your help with a small thing. I have two tables I need to get a list of the names and IDs of the people from the first table. Then use this list to get the services associated to these people. 
Please keep in mind that I need both the name and ID to identify the service.

The query is similar to the following:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name from person where customerType='specificType';
$result = mysql_query($query,$this->connection);
```

After that I loop through the result of this query to get the services list:

```
While ($list=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     $query = "SELECT serviceID, serviceName from services 
     where assignedToName='".$list['name']."' and assignedToID=".$list['id'];
 $result2 = mysql_query($query,$this->connection);

if(!$result2 || mysql_num_rows($result2) <= 0)
{//I do nothing}
else{
  if(isset($servicesList))
      { 
          //Here is the part that is not working, How to combine the results??
     $servicesList .= $result;
      } 

      else $servicesList=$result;
    }
}
//End While


if(isset($servicesList))
{ return $servicesList;}else { 
return 'error';
```

}

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Running individual queries inside a loop of results from another query is horrifically inefficient.  Eric gave you a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider using a `join` and just one query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.name, 
  s.serviceID, 
  s.serviceName 
FROM 
  person p 
LEFT JOIN 
  services s
ON 
  (p.id = s.assignedToID 
  AND 
  p.name = s.assignedToName)
WHERE 
  p.customerType='specificType'
```

Comment: Thank you, I have always had an issue with JOINs, this works perfectly